# Filter when condition returns a cats effect

Tags: scala, cats-effect

Consider the following use case:

```scala
val ds = mutable.Set[Int](1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

def check(num: Int): Boolean = num % 2 == 0

ds.filter(check)
```

Now if I have a `check` function that returns `IO[Boolean]`, how would I implement the `filter` or `filterInPlace`?

```scala
def check(num: Int): IO[Boolean] = IO.delay(num % 2 == 0)
```

Comment: `ds.toList.filterA(check)` after importing `cats.syntax.all._` that will return an `IO[List[Int]]`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez What about `filterInPlace`?

Comment: You may then execute the `IO` to the `Boolean` out of it. - But really, it doesn't make much sense to mix mutable collections an `IO`; if you don't want to use `IO` and it is coming from a third-party library I would recommend running the `IO` ASAP.